# How to create and pass an array of object to Blade's @include?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, laravel-blade

I'm new to Blade, and couldn't find how to do that.

Unfortunately, [Blade's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#including-sub-views) doesn't help much, but I've already tried the following:

```
@include('module.my-component', [
    'param' => [{
        'x' =>  'A',
        'y' => false
    }, {
        'x' => 'B',
        'y' => true
    }]
])
```

As expected, I've got the following syntax error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']'

Does anybody know the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use valid PHP syntax. This is not valid PHP:

```
[{'b' => 'a'}]
```

This is valid PHP though:

```
[
    (object) ['x' => 'B', 'y' => true],
    (object) [ ... ],
]
```

That would be an array of `stdClass` objects. When you cast an array to `object` you get an `stdClass` object with those properties.

Basically everything inside a Blade directive is a single 'string'/'expression' ... when blade compiles it replaces itself with PHP and that expression usually just gets dropped in directly, so it is all PHP in the end, so it has to be valid. You can open up any compiled view from the storage folder to see this in action.

Comment: Thank you! It worked - I'm sorry for the newbie question, I really couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: no worries ... a lot of this stuff seems kind of magical and complicated and when you dont know what is happening behind the scenes it can be difficult to know what you can and can't do